# COUNTIF multiple columns

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I am trying to get excel to count the number of persons role labelled as "Other" in a column. In this instance I have managed with `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("Other",$D$4:$D$13)))`.

However I then need to count the number of persons with "Other" in the column and with "Yes" in another column on the same Row, i tried; `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("Other",$D$4:$D$13))+ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",$H$5:$H$13)))` but it throws a #N/A error at me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [COUNTIFS](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php)

```
COUNTIFS( range1, criteria1, [range2, criteria2, ... range_n, criteria_n] )
```

Therefore something like:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"=Other",$B:$B,"=Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were so close...

You can either use:

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("Other",$D$4:$D$13))*ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",$H$5:$H$13)))`

or

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("Other",$D$4:$D$13)),--ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",$H$5:$H$13)))`